# Have an issue while split and count the data in a CSV in MONGODB(Having Null values in columns like columnname:"")

Tags: mongodb

I have  used the following script to split and count the number of data of comma separated value in a field(mongodb).
but in my case i have null values like this "" for this it shows "errmsg" : "exception: reduce -> multiple not supported yet",(this error).
if value is not null it works properly.i need to work it for column has null value like this [characters:""].kindly help.

Error:
"errmsg" : "exception: reduce -> multiple not supported yet",
"code" : 10075,
"ok" : 0

```
enter code here
map = function() {
var array = this.characters.split(',');
emit(this.characters, array.length);
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
return values;
}

result = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce" : "book", 
    "map" : map,
    "reduce" : reduce,
    "out" : "comma_result"
 });`
```

Comment: I just inserted some sample data with null values, I used your MR functions, and MR worked as expected.  Could you tell us what version of MongodB you are using?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your problem - here are two documents that I inserted: {_id:1, characters: "a,b,c"}, {_id:4, characters: ""}, and the results: {"_id" : "", "value" : 1}, {"_id" : "a,b,c", "value" : 3}

Comment: if i am put this function in to my collection error shows as "errmsg" : "exception: reduce -> multiple not supported yet",
"code" : 10075,
"ok" : 0--------i don t know what to do to clear this

Answer (score 1):

I think I have discovered the problem. Consider the following input data:

```
{_id: 1, characters: ""}
{_id: 2, characters: "a, b, c"}
{_id: 3, characters: "a, b, c"}

> db.collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: { inline : 1}})
"exception: reduce -> multiple not supported yet"
```

This error message indicates that MR currently cannot be used to return an array of values.  If you take a look at your reduce function:

```
reduce = function(key, values) {
    return values;
}
```

"values" will be an array of "array.length"s grouped together by key.  Since the key "a,b,c" was emitted twice (the same logic follows for multiple documents with ""), values (in my example) is an array with two elements, and MR cannot return arrays.

If a single document is emitted for a particular key (which is the case for _id:1), the reduce function won't be called. This explains why you don't get an error message when you don't emit null characters.

To get this MR operation to work, you need to emit a single document for {characters: ""}. If you provide additional information about your data, we may be able to help find workarounds.

EDIT:

The following reduce function will ensure that a single value, rather than an array, is returned:

```
reduce = function(key, values) {
        return values[0];
}
```

EDIT 2:

To prevent the error, "errmsg" : "exception: map invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: this.characters has no properties nofile_b:1", "code" : 9014...

```
map = function() { 
    if (this.characters != null){ 
         var array = this.characters.split(','); 
         emit(this.characters, array.length);
    } 
}
```

Comment: worked properly for this INPUT
> db.users2.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50608098379e3ec24bc8a82f"), "a" : "kljlk,jhkj,hkhkj,jkhkjhk,lokk,kjhn" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("506080a3379e3ec24bc8a830"), "a" : "kljlk,jhkj,hkhkj,jkhkjhk,lokk,kjhn,jhj,ljk,lokjj" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("506080ab379e3ec24bc8a831"), "a" : "kljlk,jhkj,hkhkj,jkhkjhk,lokk,kjhn,jhj,ljk,lokjj,loiikk" }
>

        "result" : "comma_result",
        "timeMillis" : 18,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 3,
                "emit" : 3,
                "reduce" : 0,
                "output" : 3
        },
        "ok" : 1}

Comment: showed error for this input:


> db.users1.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50607fc7379e3ec24bc8a829"), "a" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50607fd7379e3ec24bc8a82a"), "a" : "nscnd,hgbk" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50607fdd379e3ec24bc8a82b"), "a" : "nscnd,hgbk,klok" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50607fe6379e3ec24bc8a82c"), "a" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50608082379e3ec24bc8a82d"), "a" : "kljlk,jhkj,hkhkj" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5060808c379e3ec24bc8a82e"), "a" : "kljlk,jhkj,hkhkj,jkhkjhk,lokk,kjhn" }

Comment: i have to collections book(name,edition,characters(csv) and author(name,work_written(same as book name).i have create a mapreduce query to find bookname,authorname,editions and numberof characters in the book.       Kindly help me.

Comment: Am getting   this error                                                          "errmsg" : "exception: map invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: this.characters has no properties nofile_b:1",
"code" : 9014,
"ok" : 0[sry am a beginner in mongo mapreduce]

Comment: have you edited your map and reduce functions? Can you post the new functions?

Comment: map = function() {
var array = this.characters.split(',');
emit(this.characters, array.length);
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
return values[0];
}

result = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce" : "book", 
    "map" : map,
    "reduce" : reduce,
    "out" : "comma_result"
 });

Comment: try this: map = function() {
if(this.characters != null){ 
 var array = this.characters.split(','); 
 emit(this.characters, array.length);} 
}

Comment: @Jenna, +1! Thank you so much for this idea! You saved my time. Also, we can do `if (this.characters)` instead of `!= null`.