# "errmsg" : "exception: map invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: this.characters has no properties nofile_b:1",

Tags: mongodb

I have used the following script to split and count the data in characters column in MongoDB. I am getting an error while processing `null` values. Kindly help me.

```
map = function() {
    var array = this.characters.split(',');
    emit(this.characters, array.length);
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
    return values[0];
}

result = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce" : "book", 
    "map" : map,
    "reduce" : reduce,
    "out" : "comma_result1"
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
"errmsg" : "exception: map invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: this.characters has no properties nofile_b:1"
```

Comment: can you simply not emit documents with characters = null? i.e. map = function() {
if(this.characters != null){ 
 var array = this.characters.split(','); 
 emit(this.characters, array.length);} 
}

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564791/have-an-issue-while-split-and-count-the-data-in-a-csv-in-mongodbhaving-null-val/12568556#12568556

Answer (score 1):

If this.characters is null, calling this.characters.split() will produce an exception.